# Django - creating model instance when user is created

Tags: django

First of all I found some previous solutions but they are pretty outdated and not really recommended for current version of Django. What I want to do is I have a watchlist model which is bound to user by foreign key relation, what I would like to is to create a watchlist every time a user is created so it is automatically bound to the said user. I have some models and model managers but I really don't know how to connect them and would appreciate some help. I've tried a few things already but all ended up creating users but not watchlists.

```
class UserMananger(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """create and save new user"""
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
    user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self.db)
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
"""User model"""

email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = UserMananger()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


class WatchlistManager(models.Manager):
"""manage creating watchlists"""

def create_watchlist(self, user):
    watchlist = self.create(user=user)
    watchlist.save()

    return watchlist


class Watchlist(models.Model):
"""Watchlist model"""
watchlist_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.watchlist_id} {self.user}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you should use django signals**

in your models put that code .... if you changed the default user model change it from `sender=User` to `sender=yourModel`

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



 """
   models
 """


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def watchlist_create(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        watchlist.objects.create(user=instance,)
```

now every time user will be created a watchlist will be created with the same user and you can add any more fields in the create method ... even if you created a super user with the command line watchlist will be created

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work I ve a question though. What are those "instance=None, created=False" ?

Comment: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) here you will find that `instance is The actual instance being saved.
created : A boolean; True if a new record was created.` an i understand the created make sure that is a new user created not user update there info

Answer (score 1):

If each user has one watchlist then you shouldn't connect the models via ForeignKey. You shold use a OneToOneField instead.
Unless a single User can have multiple Watchlists, in this case the ForeignKey connection is correct.

I'm not familiar in the use of managers but I don't see any need to go in that direction. If i were you I would use a signal instead. You set up the signal to watch the database for new users being created, and when they are you automatically create a watchlist and attach it to that specific user.

Alternatively you can lookup the SignUp class in the Django source code and partially override it so to create a watchlist entry everytime a user signs up.

You may also wanna consider using celery to run these tasks in the background, without affecting the user experience.